# How to ignore SSL errors from http request node

Tags: node-red

I'm trying to use [node-red](http://nodered.org/) as a frontend to interface with a REST API that I'm building. My API uses https but on my local server the certificates aren't perfectly set up and when I try to use a "http request" node I get a error:

```
 UNABLE_TO_VERIFY_LEAF_SIGNATURE
```

Is there a way to configure node-red to be less strict and allow SSL protocol errors and proceed to process the http request? Did anyone create their own version of the "http request" node that is less strict than the default one?

(in the Google Chome browser I have a green padlock so SSL is nearly correct, node-red is being very picky)

---

To run node-red I use docker:

```
docker run -dp 1880:1880 -v ~/.node-red:/root/.node-red --name node-red cpswan/node-red
```

This is my node-red project sourcecode:

```
[{"id":"e246fcb9.1db9","type":"inject","name":"Trigger user/me","topic":"","payload":"","payloadType":"date","repeat":"","crontab":"","once":false,"x":200,"y":140,"z":"e7bac913.184538","wires":[["f9d78108.06288"]]},{"id":"96b8b92c.694748","type":"http request","name":"user/me","method":"GET","ret":"obj","url":"https://local.supertasker.com/api/user/me","x":711,"y":141,"z":"e7bac913.184538","wires":[["5150419b.aeafc"]]},{"id":"5150419b.aeafc","type":"debug","name":"","active":true,"console":"false","complete":"false","x":906,"y":140,"z":"e7bac913.184538","wires":[]},{"id":"f9d78108.06288","type":"function","name":"Add 'Accept:application/json' header","func":"\nmsg.headers = {\n    'Accept':'application/json'\n};\n\n// Return the message so it can be sent on\nreturn msg;","outputs":1,"valid":true,"x":464,"y":140,"z":"e7bac913.184538","wires":[["96b8b92c.694748"]]}]
```

Comment: Your likely to get more people to help posting to the node-red forum: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/node-red

Comment: @hardillb - Thanks, done: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/node-red/vj1-xF5wni8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code in `settings.js` file. Before the `module.exports` line

```
process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = "0";
```

If you want to find the file location run the node-red it, shows the file location as well.

Answer (score 5):

Currently, node-red doesn't expose a way of doing this directly, but you can set the `NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` environment variable to disable it at the node.js level:

For example:

```
NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 node red.js
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked for me. I set it in my Dockerfile  as ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0

Answer (score 0):

In case it helps anyone, here is how you can try node-red using [Docker](https://www.docker.com/) **without HTTPS errors** using the ENV var that @knolleary [brought to light](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29984172/42754) (`NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0`):

Create a `Dockerfile` with this inside:

```
FROM node:0.10
RUN npm install -g node-red
EXPOSE 1880
ENV NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/node-red"]
```

Build it:

```
docker build -t="yourname/node-red" .
```

Run it:

```
docker run -dp 1880:1880 -v ~/.node-red:/root/.node-red --name node-red yourname/node-red
```

Browse to: http://127.0.0.1:1880/

If you need the node-red app to access services running on the host, you can add the name of the service to `/etc/hosts` of the node-red container referencing the docker gateway IP:

```
docker exec node-red sh -c "echo '172.17.42.1\tmy.local.service.com\n' >> /etc/hosts"
```

After this, a node-red "http request" node can use `my.local.service.com` in the url.

Answer (score 0):

I installed **node-red** using **snapd** on ubuntu 20.04 LTS

if any one has the same issue using this tools on ubuntu, just look at:

> ***`/etc/systemd/system/snap.node-red.node-red.service`***
>
> [image: node-red service definition]

You 'il find that the app is using ***`/etc/environment`*** file to set env vars

#### Update

change **`EnvironmentFile=...`** to **`Environment="NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0"`**

After that, restart systemd and snap.node-red service with :

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload && service snap.node-red.node-red restart
```

> make sure the service is running by :
>
> ```sh
> sudo service snap.node-red.node-red status
> ```
>
> [image: node-red service]

The request should pass normally
[image: Node red HTTPs request working example]

Comment: Editing `/etc/environment` is dangerous, it sets the variable for the entire system. This edit will mean that ALL nodejs application will not verify any HTTPS connections.

Comment: You're right @hardillb, i've did an update to my answer

The idea is just set new env file on `/etc/environement.d/node-red.conf`

and set the env file on the service side

works like magic

Comment: That won't help, the content of `/etc/environment.d` is also used for the whole machine as well.

Comment: Well, in that case I just need to set the environment variable on the service file.